# Why global variable not updating value in swift 3?

Tags: ios, swift, global-variables

This is the class where the value is

```
class CurrentWeather{

    var _date:String!
    var _cityName:String!
    var _temp:Double!
    var _weatherType:String!


    var cityName:String{
        if _cityName==nil{
            _cityName = ""
        }

        return _cityName
    }
    var currentTemprature:Double{

        if _temp==nil{
            _temp = 0.0
        }

        return self._temp
    }
    var weathertype:String{
        if _weatherType==nil{
            _weatherType =  ""
        }
        return _weatherType
    }
    var date:String{

        if _date==nil{
            _date = ""
        }
     let dateFormater=DateFormatter()
        dateFormater.dateStyle = .long
        dateFormater.timeStyle = .none
        let currentDate = dateFormater.string(from: Date())
        self._date="\(currentDate)"
        return _date
     }


       func weatherDataDownload(completed : downloadComplete){
    let weatherUrl=URL(string: constant)!
    Alamofire.request(weatherUrl , method:.get).responseJSON{response in

        if let dict=response.result.value as? Dictionary<String,AnyObject>{

            if let name=dict["name"] as? String{
                self._cityName = name.capitalized
                print(name.capitalized)
            }
            if let weather=dict["weather"] as? [Dictionary<String,AnyObject>]{
                if let main=weather[0]["main"] as? String{
                    self._weatherType=main.capitalized
                    print(main.capitalized)
                }

            }
            if let tempr=dict["main"] as? Dictionary<String,AnyObject>{
                if let temp=tempr["temp"] as? Double{
                   let convertedTemp=Double(round(temp-273.15))
                    self._temp=convertedTemp
                    print(convertedTemp)
                }
            }

        }

    }
    completed()
}}
```

This is the ViewController class

```
var currentWeatherOj = CurrentWeather()


    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        table.delegate=self
        table.dataSource=self
        currentWeatherOj.weatherDataDownload {
            self.updateUIweather()
        }


    }
    func updateUIweather () {
        weatherType.text=currentWeatherOj.weathertype
        presentDate.text=currentWeatherOj.date
        presentLocation.text=currentWeatherOj.cityName
        presentTemp.text="\(currentWeatherOj.currentTemprature)"

    }
```

when I try to call in `ViewController` its showing the default value which I set inside of computed variable other than `_date` but I am able print values inside the `func` of `weatherDataDownload`.I am confused how variables in swift 3 works because of this.

Comment: You are calling `completed` outside the closure, so it is being called before the download has completed.

Comment: where it should be?. Its inside the `func` of `weatherDataDownload`

Comment: It should be the last line inside the `responseJSON` closure

Comment: if I do that I am getting error as `closure use of non-escaping parameter 'completed' may allow it to escape`

Comment: Yes, you will need to declare the `completed` parameter as `@escaping`

Comment: I did this it worked but how?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/143550/discussion-between-paulw11-and-digs).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See the comments in the following code sample.  You need to move the call to "completed()"

```
func weatherDataDownload(@escaping completed : downloadComplete) {
    let weatherUrl=URL(string: constant)!
    Alamofire.request(weatherUrl , method:.get).responseJSON { response in
        // ... leave your code here alone

        // put the call to completed() here
        completed()
    }
    // not here
}
```

When you make the all to Alamofire, it executes it's request on a background thread.  When that request completes, it calls the closure that you've defined (the one that starts "response in...").  You don't want to call `updateUIweather` until that has been done so you put the call to "completed()" inside of the same completion handler.

When the call to `completed` was outside of that completion handler, it would be called right away... immediately after the Alamofire request was sent (but before it had finished on that background thread).  None of the code in the completion handler has run yet so your variables aren't updated yet.

Finally because your `completed` closure was passed to a block that was then sent off to a background thread, that closure "escapes" the current function.  You add the @escaping so that folks reading your code will know that the closure will live on beyond the life of that function.

Comment: added @escaping per comments in main question

Comment: I added some more explanation.